# Null Values not accepting in Audit table

Tags: triggers

[image]

NULL values in fields like table *Reciever* and field *Name* and created *recieverAudit* but changes are not accepting in audit table if *reciever* table has NULL records

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what type of database you are using.

Comment: Don't paste code as image..

Comment: This is currenty a low-quality question. Links to images or even images of code are not recommended as it constitutes poor formatting.